# TCP sockets and file manipulation in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp, filesystems

I am new to Node.js and I have 2 questions about it:

- Can you create regular TCP sockets on the server's side?
- Is it possible to read/write to a file on the server's side?

That's all. Both of these are critical for putting my program on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node has inbuilt modules that have the functionality you're looking for. You can create raw TCP sockets on the server side with the native [`net`](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html) module.

```
var net = require('net');
net.createServer(function(socket) {
  socket.write('data');
  socket.end();
});
```

And there is also a [`fs`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module for file system manipulation:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var data = 'a string';
var file = './file';

fs.writeFile(file, data, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // file has been written to disk
});

// or synchronously writing a file
fs.writeFileSync(file, data);

// fetch the data asynchronously
fs.readFile(file, function(err, data) {
  // we have "a string"
});

// synchronously reading a file
var str = fs.readFileSync(file);
```

Comment: I want to create a client-like socket that connects to a server, not a server-sided TCP socket.

Comment: You asked for a "regular TCP socket on the server's side". What are you asking for then? Connecting to a TCP server with Node?

Comment: The web application will act as kind of a 'relay' to another server. It will act as a client. So I need to create client sockets.

Comment: Just use `net.Connect()`. Find it here: http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_connect_port_host_connectlistener

Comment: Okay, thank you. I  will first try to get a program from a Socket.IO tutorial running, then completely modify the code so that I can test TCP sockets.